# Serialize form data into document library with document

Tags: document-library, serialization

I don't know of the title of the question is clear enough, so let me explain:

I have a form that a user should file in, personal details, like firstname, lastname, etc. and then a file upload control from where they need to upload a document into a document library in sharepoint.

The upload part is pretty straight forward, but I'm looking for a way of serializing the information entered by the user, next to the file in a document library.

I've been told this is possible but I have been through blog after blog but nobody has a rough example of how to do this. Is this possible?

The output in the library should be:

Filename   Firstname   Lastname   Age   Date of birth

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you add these columns (First name, Last name, Age, Date of birth) to the document library where you want them to upload their documents and make them required?
In this way, you can use the OOTB upload form and once a file has been uploaded, users will be presented with the columns to be filled in.

Comment: I am currently using a list, but I stumbled upon a web site where they attached 'meta properties' to a document library without extending the library with custom columns as you explain. Also, this is a built in document library and no extra customizations are allowed to be made.

Comment: how can it be that a document library cannot be customized? btw, link here the blog you're referring to and I'll have a look

Comment: no no, i am saying business rules state that the library should not be modified

Comment: sometimes we should dare to say to the business they are just plainly dumb ;) Where are you supposed to save the additional information then?